# firebase pass data to outside variable react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to pass some data to a variable in react + typescript
here is what I am trying

```
    const data = useMemo<DummyDataType[]>(
    () => [
      {
        userId: "Foo",
        flowAmount: "Bar",
      },

    ],
    []
  );

 const arr: { userId: string; flowAmount: string }[] = [];


 var leadsRef = db.ref('users');
leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

  snapshot.forEach(item => { 
    arr.push({userId: 'test', flowAmount: 'test'})
  })

}); 



  const Table = useTable<DummyDataType>({
    columns: columns,
    data: data,
    isDataLoading: false,
    isDataLoadingError: false,
    isRowSelectable: false,
    isMultiRowSelectable: false,
  });
  return (
    <Box p="4" color="white" bg="rgb(35, 36, 41)">
        <Button colorScheme='yellow' > Save changes</Button>
      {Table}
    </Box>
  );
```

so I want to push the arr to the data variable  (the arr is just some dummy thing for me to test, i need the arr to reach the data var) now the problem is that the table loads before the firebase loads, and it does not render the arr. I think i need to change the data or the arr to some useState but I am not sure how that would work out
If I use useState

```
type DummyDataType = {
  userId: ReactNode;
  flowAmount: ReactNode;

};
    const data = useState<DummyDataType[]>(
    () => [
      {
        userId: "Foo",
        flowAmount: "Bar",
      },


    ],
    []
  );
```

I get the next  error
[image]

Comment: This isn't so much about the scope of the variable, as the items are likely added to the global `arr` just fine, as it is about *when* you then read the variable, as the rendering of your UI happens before the data has been loaded so `arr` is still empty at that point. Since you know that you need to use `useState`, did you already read the documentation for that and try to make it work in your code?

Comment: I am not sure that I need to use useState this is just something that came to my mind. I tried but got a lot of errors, i'll try to reproduce that and add it here too

Comment: ok so, ```type DummyDataType = {
  userId: ReactNode;
  flowAmount: ReactNode;

};``` ```const data = useState<DummyDataType[]>(
    () => [
      {
        userId: "Foo",
        flowAmount: "Bar",
      },


    ],
    []
  );``` and i get the error TS2554: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.

Comment: You're gonna have to use state to keep the data, so that it then rerenders the UI when you update the data. I recommend updating your question (there's an edit button under it) to show where you are stuck when using `useState` (or `setState`).